# Android Renderscript displays corrupted buffer

Tags: android, renderscript, tegra

I am developing a simple Renderscript application that does basic image manipulation. It runs fine on my Nexus 5, but not on my Shield Tablet. I have an Allocation (RGB8888) of the same size as a SurfaceView, usage is Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT. I have another Allocation of the exact same specifications, except the usage is Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT | Allocation.USAGE_IO_OUTPUT. My Renderscript has been pared down to the bare minimum (package name removed for obvious reasons):

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name()
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

#include "rs_allocation.rsh"
#include "rs_core.rsh"

void root(const uchar4 *inVal, uchar4 *outVal){
    outVal -> rgba = inVal -> rgba;
}
```

As you can see, all it does is copy the data from one Allocation to the other. I then call iosend() on the output Allocation, which is bound to a Surface. This displays the image on my Nexus 5, but results in screen corruption ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AJye.jpg)) on the Shield. The nature of the corruption leads me to believe that somehow I'm getting into memory I shouldn't be in.

What makes it really troubling is that copying the input Allocation to a Bitmap, copying the Bitmap to the output Allocation, then calling iosend() on the output Allocation works just fine on both platforms, but completely ruins any RS speed advantage I get on the Tegra K1's GPU.

Comment: Can you try "adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1" and see if this fixes the problem?

Comment: That does work, however, I purchased the Shield specifically to leverage the Kepler GPU for RenderScript. Is there a way to get it to run on GPU without the buffer corruption?

Comment: thanks, we've reproduced this and filed a bug with NVIDIA